Could not identify mongo db driver compatible with my spring boot version which is 2.5.15
i have a  problem  to identify where can i find comaptibility between mongo db driver and spring boot version  i followed this documenattion and i found that https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/preface.html  the comaptibility is based on spring data release train .
i tried used driver 4.8 which is compatible with mongo 6 now with my project that has 2.5.15 as spring boot version  but  my application crashed

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
